# Access to Amazon EC2 takes LONG time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a t2 small machine with a weird problem that cripples my site.

Access to even getting a single small logo image can take from less than a second to more than a minute. I just do F5 refresh on the browser and it takes various times to get a small png!!

I have more than 100 cpu credits.

No errors on apache error log

In my tests, I'm accessing it with the IP address to bypass the ELB, but still some refreshes in the browser takes random time from immediate to a minute! sometimes it returns 504 error because it was more than 60 seconds.

It is an Ubuntu machine that used to work ok. Apache 2.4 with KeepAliveTimeout=5

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that the site "used to work ok"

1) Check for any changes you have made to the site's configuration.   For example you might have installed a misconfigured module into apache.  If you have an old snapshot then resurrect it and compare with what you have now

2) look in the /var/log/syslog.  If there are any mysterious messages that look like a potential hardware fault then do a EC2 stop and start to move the vm to a different physical host